# what is a "discursive site"?

Tags: epistemology, semiotics

I am looking for a definition of "discursive site". I have looked up Foucault's definition of discourse, but can't find anything. Any references or explanations welcome.

Comment: It is a place where discourse takes place, a text, a website, even a concert, see elaboration by [Chicago School of Media Theory](https://lucian.uchicago.edu/blogs/mediatheory/keywords/site-2/).

Comment: oh so it's more literal than i *would* have thought confiold

Comment: It does not look as a straight transposition from French, so I guess it is some interpretation worded in English. A position taken by the speaker perhaps: a person speaking as judge. police officer etc. ("Lieu du discours" which is found in Foucault has a different meaning).

Answer (score 1):

Roland Barthes uses the term "discursive site" in the preface to *A Lover's Discourse*:

> Everything follows from this principle: that the lover is not to be
> reduced to a single symptomal subject, but rather that we hear in his
> voice what is ‘unreal,’ i.e., intractable. … What is proposed, then,
> is a portrait—but not a psychological portrait; instead, a structural
> one which offers the reader a discursive site: the site of someone
> speaking within himself, amorously, confronting the other (the loved
> object), who does not speak. (3)

The text of *A Lover's Discourse* itself is this discursive site, by which I take it Barthes means that he does not wish to describe the lover's discourse using the metalanguage of philosophy but to seek to recreate the lover's unilateral discourse ("someone speaking within himself … confronting the other") between himself and the reader. A discursive site would thus be any situation, whether virtual (in the sense of mediated or textual) or non-virtual (in the sense of unmediated), where discourse takes 'place.' Discourse, by contrast, describes the lived aspect of language, language as acts of communication between people. A conversation between two people is the simplest example of a discursive site I can think of.

Comment: "il donne a lire une place de parole; la place de quelqu'un qui parle" in the original, so there is no "reader" and no discursivity and just "a place".

Comment: @Sand1: Barthes is well known for speakimg about readers and readers. You seem to have extracted a single sentence in French to create a whole world of meaning that is just flatly wrong.